# На чём лучше писать сайты?

Tags: html

Dreamviewer? Что ещё можно попробывать?

Comment: **лучше** писать на том на чем вам удобно, если вам удобно работать с dreamweaver - работайте, если нет - ищите и **пробуйте сами** другие решения.

Comment: Можно попробовать [KompoZer](kompozer.net)

Comment: Я бы вообще про Дримвивер забыл, как-то лет 5 назад попробовал его и до сих пор плююсь.

а про Notepad++  - люди нафига вам блокноты?
Ну если вы кодите нормальные проекты неужели сложно поставить хороший редактор к примеру NetBeans

Comment: Notpead++ это не просто блокнот =)

Я пробовал и eclipse и netbeans и еще огромное множество всяческих ide, какой либо существенной пользы не ощутил. А вот по тормозам все без исключения дают дай боже

Да и какая разница - как я уже писал нужно использовать то что тебе удобно а не то что модно

Answer (score 1):

emacs и vi попробуйте, вам понравится. Еще есть редактор ее, он для новичков.

Comment: После dreamveaver vi и emacs? :D

Да вы суров, однако

Comment: Если бы человек поискал в интернете, вместо того чтобы создавать еще одну тему, он бы получил те ответы что уже пошли ниже. Я просто хотел внести в эту цепочку из дежавю какое то разнообразие :)

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans. Простота и эффективность. Много лестных отзывов. Советую

Answer (score 1):

Всё время работал на notepad++  и до сих пор, но всё же решил под php взять Eclipse IDE, совместно с np++.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону [bluefish](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl), хороший редактор по-моему.

Answer (score 0):

дома Dreamweaver на win, на убунте Bluefish кажется(обычно хватает просто редактора gedit:) ), на работе вообще Visual Studio, кстати удобно(вёрстка+js), на пхп правда придётся наверное плагин ставить, так как синтаксис вроде не поддерживается, если пишете на asp.net, тогда Visual Studio вне конукренции))
в последнее время вообще Notepad++ всё чаще юзаю, ибо комп старый, чтоб не тормозил))))))

Answer (score 0):

Использую Visual Studio и Aptana Studio

Answer (score 0):

Работаю через `Notepad++` для удаленного соединения использую плагин `FTP_synchronize` + `keep alive` режим соединения чтобы связь не обрывалась.

Answer (score 0):

NotePade++ - никаких заморочек и все необходимое есть: подсветка,автодополнение и плагины различные.

Answer (score 0):

[WebStorm - JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)
Я уже не представляю, как без этого обходиться. Тут даже отличнейший `JS`-отладчик есть.